# Distributional convergence question for Feller processes

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory

To briefly go over the setup, $S$ the state space is a separable locally compact metric space, and $C_0$ is the space of continuous functions on $S$ that vanish at infinity.  $D$ is the space of Cadlag paths with the usual measurable structure, and $X_t$ are the corresponding coordinate maps.  The Feller property is supposed to (According to Liggett) imply that if $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $S$, then relative to the probability measures $P_{x_n}$, all the coordinate functions $X_t$ obey that for $t$ fixed, $(X_t, P_{x_n})\rightarrow^w (X_t, P_x)$ where the parentheses emphasizes the fact that the measure, which is usually understood, is important when it comes to distributional, or weak, convergence.  Recall that this means one has convergence of integrals of the pushforward measure against any continuous bounded function.

Effectively, in the more analytic language of the Riesz Representation theorem, I think what I'm asking may come down to the question of when a continuous linear functional on the space of continuous bounded functions is fully determined by its action on only those that vanish at infinity, which is itself an integration functional by RRT.  But this latter description is more of an intuition of mine rather than a precise statement, so if I have accidentally made any precise statements in the second paragraph, please don't assume them in a solution.

Comment: Since it came up in an exchange with a friend, I thought I should mention that by Hahn-Banach, one can show that uniqueness of extensions from $C_0$ to $C_b$, the the space of bounded continuous functions, is not automatic. Existence is, because of RRT, but to disprove uniqueness one can consider the space $C_0\oplus\mathbb{R}$.  Then one uses Hahn Banach to choose any behavior of the functional on the constant functions component.  This is legal because the constant functions are bounded distance from $C_0$ in the sense that for any constant, that point is of >0 distance from the space $C_0$.

Comment: All references to topology, distance, etc. are relative to sup.